# Ms Dynamics AX - How to let the table lend record only once?

Tags: connection, axapta, microsoft-dynamics

I'm new to programming. I'm working on MS Dynamics AX and I have a problem.

I'm making simple project: car rental:

Three simple tables:

- cars,
- customers,
- transactions.

I want to know how to restrict to assign a car to ONLY ONE customer.

Now I can make transactions like, for example:

Mr. Jones -> AUDI A3(ABC 1234A)
Mr. Brian -> AUDI A3(ABC 1234A)

in the same time, and its bad. They should not be able to rent the same car at the same time.

Help me.

Comment: Could you post a list of fields of your tables, especially the transactions table?

Comment: cars: id, brand, mark, numberOfSeats, cubicCapacity, color ...
customer: id, name, lastName, localization, register date ...
transactions: id, refToCustomers, refToCars, rentDate, backRentDate, totalCost ...

Comment: I'm assuming that `rentDate` is the start and `backRentDate` is the end of the rent period? Could you edit your question and include the fields and additional information from the comments there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like most of the time there are a couple of different ways you could achieve what you want.

My recommendation would be to make the `transactions` table a [valid time state table](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg861781.aspx) (assuming you are working with version 2012 or higher). But for someone new to programming, this may be a difficult concept at first.

A straigtforward solution would be to overwrite the `validateWrite` method of the `transactions` table and check if any records already exist that rent the car the in the desired time period. This could look similar to the following code (assuming that `rentDate` is the start and `backRentDate` is the end of the rent period):

```cs
public boolean validateWrite()
{
    Transactions alreadyExistingTransaction;
    boolean      ret;
    ;

    ret = super();
    select firstOnly alreadyExistingTransaction 
        where alreadyExistingTransaction.refToCars == this.refToCars
           && alreadyExistingTransaction.rentDate <= this.rentDate
           && (alreadyExistingTransaction.backRentDate >= this.rentDate
            || alreadyExistingTransaction.backRentDate == dateNull())
           && alreadyExistingTransaction.RecId != this.RecId;
    if (alreadyExistingTransaction.RecId != 0)
    {
        ret = checkFailed(strFmt("Car %1 is already rented to %2 from %3 till %4.",
                                 alreadyExistingTransaction.refToCars,
                                 alreadyExistingTransaction.refToCustomers,
                                 alreadyExistingTransaction.rentDate,
                                 alreadyExistingTransaction.backRentDate));
    }

    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Another option (ignoring time) would be to add a unique index on Car and Customer in the transaction table.